# CRTP Singleton Incomplete type or Non-literal type

Tags: c++, static, singleton, crtp

I'm trying to make a CRTP Singleton. There's a couple examples on here already. I'm not sure how mine is different or why it fails to compile. First attempt:

```
template<class Impl>
class Base
{
public:
  static const Impl& getInstance();
  static int foo(int x);
private:
  static const Impl impl{};
};
template<class Impl> inline
const Impl& Base<Impl>::getInstance()
{
  return impl;
}
template<class Impl> inline
int Base<Impl>::foo(int x)
{
  return impl.foo_impl(x);
}

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1>
{
public:
  int foo_impl(int x) const;
};
int Derived1::foo_impl(int x) const
{
  return x + 3;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  const Derived1& d = Derived1::getInstance();
  std::cout << Derived1::foo(3) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

g++ 7.4.0 tells me: `error: in-class initialization of static data member ‘const Derived1 Base<Derived1>::impl’ of incomplete type`.

Well. Ok then. Not sure why that type isn't complete. Try:

```
 . . .
 private:
   static constexpr Impl impl{};
 };
```

Now we fail at link time: `undefined reference to 'Base<Derived1>::impl'`
Really?! Looks defined and initialized to me... But even if it did link I have a Derived with a non-trivial destructor so then the compiler is going to bomb at compiletime complaining about a non-literal type used in constexpr.

Why isn't Derived1 complete? How can I build this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incomplete type error comes from the fact that you use `impl` in `getInstance` before it exists.

One way to fix this is initializing `impl` outside the class definition and make sure it's initialized before being used:

```
template <class Impl>
const Impl Base<Impl>::impl {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing your `getInstance` function in this way:

```cpp
template <class Impl>
inline const Impl& Base<Impl>::getInstance() {
    static const Impl impl{};
    return impl;
}
```

and then in `foo` function

```cpp
template <class Impl>
inline int Base<Impl>::foo(int x) {
    return getInstance().foo_impl(x);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMTO8ADqgWF1tPYYmgl4%2BanQ2do5GLm6SAAyKypiqfgwEzMQEAcam5koqYbRpGQQRDs6u7orpmdlBnNUlZVExZnEAlIqoBsTIHADkUgDMtsiGWADU4kM66goExJjMRtPY4nEAgusbY8wKChMAIq54AG6Y6JzTspvbBJhGHsL30zq7%2BxMAko%2Bsq9vvB2ke0w23EAHYbhsPAYnKw8MgQNsJhN5sw1MgJmhaPMvj8pAA2CbATAET7Y9K0PoQdrXJEo9Loia2AgTGioCDMiYADxpQ0hHmIZzRHDpAHpRajGVicd8nky8RDwYdabcwcq%2BXcHk9ha8AbinqsmbQ4XZ/nQZXjJISgUpXrLfkNsCAQMTSeSRFSaarIcjkZL4ZjzSz7fKDYq1SqNr6JosCD1aKGHZClZqfjqZnr7YbbCaQZtOTaQTMs47nWyOfRuV6torNsjY/GiSSyajKZhqQA6NkAfTwPwgPMjKdumz1x0F50uExAE2hsIDhde47OFyujtBtahMLhCLpnJ7faeFZZPMD5KHEY1%2Bcry8nnDLqFQvf7nNP0oIG59MZJja5UxkExDBeyojhsnJGMwtjHhMGTAMgpCYggGQAFTITBxDAKc1bgl%2B75HCcd4EhM6BTEMhz4ROq7Oq6LYUp6kZ%2BgQ6DOmgBgsq8rwUSulwPuyQztKROicfMzEgJYSZ0g2xAJnEwH9J0rAgP0ACs/SkKY/RxGpqBKUJMhyCi3S9Jg/5DJwakEEpWntJ0ADWIDcAAnB2AAcylOdw%2BJDEMcQ8JInD4kISncGpGlaaQOn9GpCggAklmafJpBwLAMCICgqCPHg7BkBQEBoJl2Uuo55hUFl9zEDFEBOFZalOLYGQAJ5KeZpD5UYWgEAA8saTUJaQWAQaI7A1f1eCLCk5wxX1mBcskbEDOFzLKCNcJOMQjV6FgzUWYKRjbZ0ND0EwbAcDw/BmEIIhiHIchCHgTgxZAnSoB4hRTQAtCJ0yHBI%2BkyJwLX5MkhSaNodSmA0ljNBUbgNCEvh0ODwTeAjtDQ9ElQNEDKR0MUtT6DkgjY4UeOlLY5QY7DjT44EEPU2TkQw1wnQKEZfTM0FKmhSNkVci5%2BLvfi3BEsgGLOZIEwQLghAkKZDQTHoBWuKZkgCXpsgyBZNU2aQ9nKXEHY8PrylDPi%2BKOW5YIudwymcyFpB7fr6k80p0WxaQ8XWUlqUQEg3QENCBDkJQ%2BUeFllTmBcMtU4djAsMNZ0AO7rR4%2B2c6pzt9ZFwwS4nhAINy/OC8LcFix2khawlOsIEsWBuNSdtqY7CRhdpruKO7nvyXZID64bNtxCbZsW8pVs25zQzc1n7ddzrin9BXmfhZFlfWZ05wVX4DlAA%3D%3D%3D)

Answer (score 1):

To the point of time that `Base<Derived1>` is instantiated (right at the start of the definition of `Derived1`) the class `Derived1` is incomplete, since it is that untill the end of its declaration. It is indeed not possible to have a complete type in the CRTP, since the derived type will never be complete before you have declared its inheritance.

For non-static data members the only way around that is to use some kind of pointer to the incomplete type (most probably a `std::unique_ptr`). For static members this does also work, but can also just split the declaration and the definition of a static member. So instead of

```
template<Impl>
struct Base {
   static Impl impl{};
};
```

write

```
template<Impl>
struct Base {
    static Impl impl;
};
```

and define it like this

```
template<Impl>
static Base<Impl>::impl ={};
```

after `Derived1` is complete. (Note that I am not sure how this works for private static members). In my opinion it would be cleanest, if each implementation would do this for itself, i.e. after `Derived1` is complete add

```
template<>
static Base<Derived1>::impl = {};
```

otherwise getting the order right for multiple implementations will be tricky, I think.